# Prevent Twitter JS code from displaying

Tags: javascript, twitter

I've been implementing the new Twitter API on my website and occasionally when it refreshes the javascript code I got from twitter will appear.
Does anyone know a solution/workaround for this?

Sure thing.  This is straight from twitter itself.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-dnt="true" href="https://twitter.com/somebody"  data-widget-id="api key">Tweets by @somebody</a>
<script type="text/javascript">!function (d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); } } (document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're describing.  Can you post some code?

Comment: Looks like I have this figured out.  It was some old javascript on our end.  My bad.